# Is Compatibility Mode available in Windows 7 Home?

Tags: windows-7, upgrade, compatibility

I'm going to look at a problem on a PC with Windows 7 Home (not Premium I'm guessing). Is Compatibility Mode available in Windows 7 Home?

I hear it is in Home Premium. I'm not talking about XP-mode which I understand is something different.

If my user does not have Home Premium, how easy is it to upgrade from Home to Home Premium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I’ve found online it looks like compatibility mode is available in each edition of Windows 7 (even though I can’t seem to find one, solid source that will confirm this).

Upgrading to a ‘Higher” edition of Windows 7 is super simple by using [Windows Anytime Upgrade](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/windows-anytime-upgrade).

> Getting started
>
> 1. Decide whether you want to purchase the upgrade online or to go to a local retail store to buy a Windows Anytime Upgrade key.
> 2. Download and run the Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor. It can help you determine which features and editions of Windows 7 will run on your PC.
> 3. On your PC, open Windows Anytime Upgrade by clicking the Start button, typing Windows Anytime Upgrade in the search box, and then clicking Windows Anytime Upgrade in the list of results.
> 4. Follow the instructions on the screen for online purchases or follow the instructions that came with your upgrade key.

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/Make-older-programs-run-in-this-version-of-Windows says "Applies to all editions. Also... jangling in my head is that MS decided to make all "Home" editions "Home Premium" editions as the differences were minimal and moaned about. Thanks for the upgrade link.